# UIActivityViewController : Possible to implement flow with a configuration step?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

An app I am building needs functionality to share video.
I have successfully implemented a UIActivityViewController for this, with a custom UIActivityItemProvider to dynamically generate the video output.

However, I would like the user to be able to select an output quality for the video as well. I would like the flow to be:

1. User taps share button UIActivityViewController appears
2. User taps desired activity
3. Options for video quality are presented
4. User taps desired quality
5. UIActivityItemProvider generates video at desired quality
6. Video is shared to selected service

However I don't see any options to hook items 3 and 4 into the flow.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with trying to implement a similar flow, and I couldn't get anything that was close enough to work for my case. So I ended up going about it in a different way, that accomplished my same goal (for the end users experience). Here's what I did:

1. User taps share button, and I present a UIActionSheet with the share options (in your case, the quality options).
2. User taps desired option, and then UIActivityViewController is presented.
3. Item is shared, with appropriate options, to the selected share service.

It actually turned out to be a really nice flow in the end. However, it doesn't solve the problem of allow option configuration after the UIActivityController is displayed, it just shuffles the flow around so that the end result is the same - but working within the confines of the UIActivityViewController.

I hope this alternative is helpful to anyone that finds this older post and is curious about how to do this. Also, if there is a way to do this in the primary flow as the OP asks, I'd love to know that as well.